# Is it possible to map a domain to a specific page?

Tags: domain-mapping

Is it possible to map a domain to a specific page on a website?

For example, can the domain www.shoes.com, be mapped to www.onlinestore.com/newyork/queens/shoes.php?

Answer (score 1):

Via DNS, no. A domain name is just a name->ip mapping.

You can set up a webserver to service `shoes.com`, and simply have all hits on that site get redirected to the onlinstore.com sub-page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In Python and JavaScript, you'd write this:

```
urlmap = {'www.shoes.com': www.onlinestore.com/newyork/queens/shoes.php?'}
```

At least, that would be the case if this was a programming question, which it doesn't appear to be.